# Was Ionic 4 Beta removed from NPM?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Looks like the beta version of **Ionic 4** was removed from NPM

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic?activeTab=versions

is this correct?

if so is it going to be added **Ionic 5.beta**?

Answer (score 2):

You might confuse Ionic CLI (i.e. the package you link to) and [@ionic/core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/core?activeTab=versions) library, which version 4.0.0-beta.0 was announced in [Ionic Blog](https://blog.ionicframework.com/announcing-ionic-4-beta/).